# Saving EditText input and restoring it?

Tags: android

New to Android development here. I'm currently making an app that has a EditText and a Button. If that Button is clicked, a new Activity will start and display whatever text is inputted from the previous activity.

Whenever I click on the up button on the action bar present in the second activity, it will then bring me back to the first activity. But the inputted text on the EditText view is lost.

I'm a dummy. Probably, I already found a solution through Google but I don't understand any of them. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to read the activity lifecycle thoroughly. it will solve your problem. Google developer guide has a precise explanation.

Comment: @NirajAdhikari this will not solve the problem, unless the data is saved somewhere in the app. Like SharedPreferences or in Bean.

Comment: i am well aware of the fact. i suggested so because the person would eventually get idea about when (lifecycle callbacks) and where to save the data and how to retrieve it and repopulate the views on reading the docs thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's strange, the text should remain unless you are modifying it somewhere in that process, or somehow you are instantiating a new instance in your first activity when you exit out of the second one.

Either way, you can always read the text of the `EditText` when you switch to the second activity and then write it back in when you return to the first activity.

Save it like this:

```
EditText yourTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourTextBoxId);
String previousText = yourTextBox.getText();
```

And restore it like this:

```
yourTextBox.setText(previousText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to one of the sample called as `PersistentState.java` in Android-SDK, it's located under

`~/Android-SDK/samples/android-xx/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/`.

To start with learn about [LifeCycle of an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html). To save the data learn about [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).